# CloudFormation - Updating the SecurityGroupIds of an ec2 instance it recreates the instance instead of modifying the same

Tags: amazon-cloudformation

I created ec2 instance with cloudformation. When I try to update the securitygroup of the instance in the same template , cloudformation recreates the instance instead of modifying the same (Like in terraform). How to update the SecurityGroup of instance without recreating it ?

For example the below template -

```
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-0ed9277fb7eb570c9
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-09d68774a93ec40df
```

Now If I try to add another SecurityGroupIds it recreates the ec2 -

```
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-0ed9277fb7eb570c9
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-09d68774a93ec40df
        - sg-05555951931eeaca7
```

Comment: Documentation says update of that property creates interruptions but not replacement. Are you changing anything else at the same time? I would expect this to work. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroupids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this with a copy of your stack, and see the same behaviour. However, when I create a new VPC (which is recommended security practice, the default VPC should be avoided) the security groups update cleanly without replacement.

I suspect this is to do with the behaviour on the default VPC, and is expected (but odd) behaviour!

I would recommend you create a new VPC with subnets - the VPC wizard does a good job here. Go to Services -> VPC to get started.

My testing file:

```
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      # default Amazon Linux AMI
      ImageId: ami-0d37e07bd4ff37148
      SecurityGroupIds:
        # first security group I created in default:
        - sg-0d16f8e62054c9ed0
        # second security group I created in default:
        - sg-0ffc2a7a986ab0e8c

  OtherEc2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-0d37e07bd4ff37148
      # Private subnet (no internet) in a new VPC:
      SubnetId: subnet-08dc2104d169a815e
      SecurityGroupIds:
        # First SG in that VPC:
        - sg-0ebec69e461a555b8
        # Second SG in that VPC:
        - sg-00b18a57193a12f5c
```